# Google App Script - Emailing from Google sheets and I receive error Failed to send email: no recipient

Tags: javascript, google-apps

I have written a Google App Script to send out performance summary emails. However, even though the script does indeed send out the emails, I am receive the error Failed to send email: no recipient.

From what I have found searching this site it is because of the getLastRow() section. I do need this script to be dynamic because the number of rows is likely to change frequently.

My spreadsheet has a button on row 1 that activates the script to run when clicked.

Row 2 is my headers.

Row 3 is where the data begins.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
function SummaryEmail() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
var range = sheet.getRange(3, 1, lastRow-1,21);
Logger.log(range.getA1Notation());
var UserData = range.getValues();
for (i in UserData) {
var row = UserData[i];
var period = row[0];
var username = row[1]
var total = row[2]
var goal = row[3]
var uniqutotal = row[4]
var uniqueratio = row[5]
var days = row[6]
var avgperday = row[7]
var totalhours = row[8]
var avgperhour = row[9]
var wheel = row[10]
var market = row[11]
var type = row[12]
var email = row[13]
var email2 = row[14]
var email3 = row[15]
var manager = row[16]
var assignments = row[17]
var conversions = row[18]
var offers = row[19]
var percent = row[20]
MailApp.sendEmail(row[13], "Status Report for " + period + "", "Message")
}
}
```

Comment: Use the debugger to set a break pint at the `MailApp.sendEmail(...` line and see what the value of your variables are.  Is row[13] and email a valid email address?  For help using the debugger see: [Troubleshooting](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting)

Comment: @Karl_S Thank you for your response. I ran the debugger and all of the variables return the appropriate date from each column. Any other errors you see with my code that would cause this?

Answer (score 0):

The solution ended up being pretty simple. It turned out my range was incorrect and needed to be changed.

On the line that had

```
var range = sheet.getRange(3, 1, lastRow-1,21);
```

It needs to be changed to

```
var range = sheet.getRange(3, 1, lastRow-2,21);
```

Hope this helps anyone that ran into my same issue. Thanks!